# cancelDiscovery keeps returning false

Tags: android, bluetooth

I find all available bluetooth devices, and then when the user clicks an element in the list, I would like to pair my device with the address selected, and cancel discovery. However, my cancelDiscovery() call on the bluetooth adapter always returns false. In the android docs it says the adapter must be in STATE_ON for cancelDiscovery() to return true. However, when I call btAdapter.getState() it returns a value of 12, which is STATE_ON. My code is below, does anyone know what else can be wrong?

I don't understand how cancelDiscovery() is returning false, when the current state is STATE_ON. The docs say that it should return true if the state is STATE_ON, and false for all other values.

```
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.randomUUID();

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnScanDevice = (Button) findViewById( R.id.scandevice );

    stateBluetooth = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.bluetoothstate );
    startBluetooth();

    listDevicesFound = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.devicesfound );
    btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( AndroidBluetooth.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    listDevicesFound.setAdapter( btArrayAdapter );

    CheckBlueToothState();

    btnScanDevice.setOnClickListener( btnScanDeviceOnClickListener );

    registerReceiver( ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND ) );

    listDevicesFound.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
      {
          Log.i("Discovery: ", Integer.toString( myBtAdapter.getState() ) );
          boolean success = myBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
          myBtDevice = btDevicesFound.get( arg2 );
          try {
              btSocket = myBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID );
              iStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
              oStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Bluetooth not available, or insufficient permissions" );
          } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer One" );
          }
          CheckBlueToothState();
          try {
              btSocket.connect();
          } catch ( IOException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Problems arose while attempting to connect." );
          } catch ( NullPointerException e ) {
              Log.e( "Bluetooth Socket", "Null Pointer Two" );
          }
      }

  });
}

private void CheckBlueToothState() {
    if( myBtAdapter == null ) {
        stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT supported" );
    } else {
        if( myBtAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
            if( myBtAdapter.isDiscovering() ) {
                stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is currently " +
                        "in device discovery process." );
            } else {
                stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is Enabled." );
                btnScanDevice.setEnabled( true );
            }
        } else {
            stateBluetooth.setText( "Bluetooth is NOT enabled" );
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
            startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
        }
    }
}

private Button.OnClickListener btnScanDeviceOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick( View arg0 ) {
        btArrayAdapter.clear();
        myBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
};


@Override
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    if( requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT ) {
        CheckBlueToothState();
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals( action ) ) {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra( BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE );
            btDevicesFound.add( btDevice );
            btArrayAdapter.add( btDevice.getName() + "\n" + btDevice.getAddress() );
            btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }           
    }
};
public static void startBluetooth(){
    try {
        myBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        myBtAdapter.enable();
    } catch ( NullPointerException ex ) {
        Log.e( "Bluetooth", "Device not available" );
    }
}

public static void stopBluetooth() {
    myBtAdapter.disable();
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cleaned my project and it worked fine for anyone looking at this thread for answers.